# p:column instead c:foreach on datatable primefaces cannot show result

Tags: jsf, primefaces, foreach

i have a problem with p:column instead c:foreach
when i show size of list in p:column value found
but when i used p:column instead c:foreach result is empty

```
<h:form id="frmDataTable">
        <p:dataTable widgetVar="widgetVarCrudDataTable" var="list"
             id="dataTable"
            value="#{workshiftListBean.listWorkshiftRqDtl}"
            emptyMessage="No record found">
            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                <p:row>
                    <c:forEach items="#{workshiftListBean.listVoHeader}"
                        var="listHeader">
                        <p:column headerText="#{listHeader.headerDays}"
                            styleClass="#{listHeader.weekendStyle}" />
                    </c:forEach>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <c:forEach items="#{workshiftListBean.listVoHeader}"
                        var="listHeader">
                        <p:column headerText="#{listHeader.headerDates}"
                            styleClass="#{listHeader.weekendStyle}" />
                    </c:forEach>
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>


            <!--size found -->
            <p:column>
                    #{list.listVoShift.size()}
            </p:column>

            <!-- but when i used c:foreach this result is empty -->
            <c:forEach items="#{list.listVoShift}" var="shift">
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText value="#{shift.property}" />
                </p:column>
            </c:forEach>
```

my code problem in :
         
                
                        #{list.listVoShift.size()}

```
            <!-- but when i used c:foreach this result is empty -->
            <c:forEach items="#{list.listVoShift}" var="shift">
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText value="#{shift.property}" />
                </p:column>
            </c:forEach>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: thanks for your question..
i didnt know why when i used c:foreach in p:columnGroup its work perfectly...
but when i used c:foreach outside p:columnGroup its doesnt work
can u explain it please, or anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ui:repeat var="shift" value="#{list.listVoShift}">
        <p:column>
               <p:inputText value="#{shift.property}" />
           </p:column>
    </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: This will not work as *ui:repeat* is not recognised by *p:datatable*.